# Defining Tuple types

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections, typing, static-typing

For this type :

```
val t :  (String, Array[((String, String), Double)]) =  ("a", Array((("a", "b"), 1.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0)))
```

should I not be able to use also this type definition :

```
val t : Tuple2[String , Array[Tuple2[[String , String] , Double]]] = ("a", Array((("a", "b"), 1.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0)))
```

But receive this error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - identifier expected but '[' found. - wrong number of type arguments for Tuple2, 
 should be 2 - only classes can have declared but undefined members
```

Is Tuple2 (or TupleN) not allowed when defining a type ?

Comment: You are missing one `Tuple2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem specifically there:

```
Tuple2[[String , String] , Double]]
```

`[String, String]` is a nonsense, you probably wanted `Tuple2[Tuple2[String , String] , Double]]`, or `((String , String) , Double)`

Answer (score 1):

of course `TupleN` can be used while defining the type:

you are missing Tuple2

```
val t : Tuple2[String , Array[Tuple2[[String , String] , Double]]] = ("a", Array((("a", "b"),  1.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0)))
                                     ^
                                     //missing Tuple2
val t : Tuple2[String , Array[Tuple2[Tuple2[String , String] , Double]]] = ("a", Array((("a", "b"), 1.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0)))
```